# Apache Camel: Dead Letter Channel is not working

Tags: java, apache-camel

I don't know what I am missing but My dead letter channel is not kicking off. Camel configurations are defined as

```
    <bean id="myDeadLetterHandler" class="org.apache.camel.builder.DeadLetterChannelBuilder">
        <property name="deadLetterUri" value="activemq:queue:TESTQUEUE"/>
    </bean>
        <route errorHandlerRef="myDeadLetterHandler">
            <from uri="seda:elixirBatchQueue" />
            <convertBodyTo type="String"/>
            <inOnly uri="activemq:queue:someQ"/>
        </route>
```

Here **someQ** doesn't exist and TESTQUEUE does exist.
Logs are:

```
DEBUG SendProcessor:114 - >>>> Endpoint[activemq://queue:someQ] Exchange[Message: org.dom4j.tree.DefaultDocument@afdb52]
DEBUG FailoverTransport:660 - Reconnect was triggered but transport is not started yet. Wait for start to connect the transport.
DEBUG FailoverTransport:302 - Started.
DEBUG FailoverTransport:653 - Waking up reconnect task
DEBUG FailoverTransport:683 - urlList connectionList:[tcp://localhost:61616], from: [tcp://localhost:61616]
DEBUG FailoverTransport:855 - Attempting connect to: tcp://localhost:61616
```

Comment: What version of Camel and ActiveMQ are you using?

Comment: @sully6768 I am using Camel 2.9.2 and ActiveMQ 5.5.1

Comment: @sully6768 I have found one issue with my test case. When I am trying to connect to 'someQ' which I have already deleted. After hitting the route activemq is automatically creating it and messages are successfully going there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working fine now. Active MQ was creating deleted queues when route was initiating the deleted queue.

Comment: @ClausIbsen Sure. I can only mark it as answered after two days.